# Can you see why this form fails to work when php is upgraded from 5.2 to version 5.4

Tags: php

My host is about to upgrade from php 5.2 to 5.4 and I have a small amount of testing time. I have found all works except for one contact form on my homepage. When on 5.2 it sends the email and gives a positive result. On 5.4 it does not send the email and gives the user a negative result. Any help with this is most appreciated.

```
<?php 
include_once("includes/includes.inc.php");

if(isset($_POST) && (isset($_POST['contactusfrm']) == 1))
{
#print_arr($_POST);
$quotefrm   = array($_POST);
$emailObj = &new eMail();
if(isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email']!="")
{
    $emailBody  = contactUs($quotefrm);
    $semail     = $quotefrm[0]['email'];
    $contactus = $emailInfo->email;
}

$emailInfo = GetContactusEmailInfo();
$subject="Contact Us";
    #echo "<br /><br /><br />".$emailBody ; die();
if ($emailObj->SendEmail($semail, $emailInfo->email , $subject , $emailBody, ""))
    $contactusMessage = "Your Comments has been sent.";
else
    $contactusMessage = "Error sending please re-try.";         

}
?>
```

Comment: Adjust your `error_reporting` and provide us please with the error message.

Comment: I suspect you should get an error saying ``Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated`` because of ``$emailObj = &new eMail();``. As of PHP 5.3+, you shouldn't be assigning a new object/class as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

That is because `Call-time pass by reference` has been removed from PHP 5.4.

For the full-list. See [`here`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.incompatible.php).

You are doing that in this line.

```
$emailObj = &new eMail(); //which will issue a FATAL Error and your code execution stops here.
```